# How to calculate laplacian form gradient?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, gradient, laplacian

I am dealing with shadow removal. First I have to calculate gradient from the image in both directions. g(x,y) = -2*f(x,y) + f(x+1,y) + f(x,y+1). Afterwards, I do some calculation on the gradient and modify it a bit.

The problem comes when I have to calculate Laplacian (second derivative) from the modified gradient.

I know that the Laplacian filter has a matrix: [0,1,0: 1,-4,1; 0,1,0].
But the questions is how to calculate the Laplacian from the gradient, if the cells are already modified?

Calculation of gradient:

```
[Gx,Gy] = imgradientxy(img_G,'intermediate');
greenGradient = Gx + Gy;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this matlab code?  I think this needs a matlab tag.

Comment: You have to compute the Laplacian of the gradient, or the Laplacian of the original image given the gradient?

Comment: I have some image where shadows are present. First I calculate the gradient, where I can remove shadows based on gradient magnitude and invariant image. From there on, I have to calculate Laplacian from the gradient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calculating gradient using `imgradientxy(I,'intermediate')`:

```
GX(j, i)  = I(j, i+1) - I(j, i)
GY(j, i)  = I(j+1, i) - I(j, i)
```

And the Laplacian:

```
L(j, i)   = I(j, i-1) + I(j, i+1) + I(j-1, i) + I(j+1, i) - 4*I(j, i)
```

Now if we calculate gradient of `GX` and `GY`:

```
GGX(j, i) = GX(j, i) - GX(j, i-1)
          = I(j, i+1) - I(j, i) - I(j, i) + I(j, i-1)
          = I(j, i-1) + I(j, i+1) - 2*I(j, i)
GGY(j, i) = I(j-1, i) + I(j+1, i) - 2*I(j, i)
```

So

```
L(j, i) = GGX(j, i) + GGY(j, i)
```

Note that there is on pixel offset between methods used to find gradient of `I` and gradient of `GX` and `GY`.

```
I =   im2double(imread('coins.png'));
[GX, GY] = imgradientxy(I,'intermediate');
L =   imfilter(I, [0 1 0; 1 -4 1; 0 1 0], 'replicate');
GGX = imfilter(GX, [0 0 0; -1 1 0; 0 0 0], 'replicate');
GGY = imfilter(GY, [0 -1 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 0], 'replicate');
L2 =  GGX+GGY;
E =   (L2-L).^2;
```

[image]